# What does the function 'vDSP_vfltu16' (in vDSP) actually do?

Tags: ios, accelerate-framework

It is a function in vDSP in iOS. The reference said this function

```
Converts an array of unsigned 16-bit integers to single-precision floating-point values.
```

But what actually is created? For example, I have a series of 16-bit integers storing phonetic samples. What do I actually get when I call this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is *created*. You pass in an array of N unsigned 16 bit short ints in the `A` parameter and an array of N floats in the `__vDSP_C` parameter and the routine converts the unsigned short int values to floats. E.g. if `A[0] = 42` then `__vDSP_C[0]` will be set to `42.0f`.

```
void vDSP_vfltu16 (
   unsigned short *A,
   vDSP_Stride __vDSP_I,
   float *__vDSP_C,
   vDSP_Stride __vDSP_K,
   vDSP_Length __vDSP_N
);
```

There is reasonable documentation on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know that if the floats created has any meanings.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "meaning". For each unsigned int in the input the corresponding float will be the same value as the unsigned int, but expressed as a single precision float.

Comment: Do you mean that they are of the same value?